# Modifying /etc/fstab makes the system boot up in emergency mode

Tags: boot, server, mount, ssh, fstab

I am mounting my user filesystem in a server I connect to through SSH as a remote filesystem in my local Ubuntu machine.

For that I have been following the instructions in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh).

The first part, mounting the system, works fine (though I have to remove the `defer_premissions` option for it to work).

But I also tried the second part, editing `/etc/fstab` to mount the remote filesystem on boot, and it made my system boot up in emergency mode.

The problem got fixed immediatly as soon as I removed the `sshfs#root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/droplet` line from `/etc/fstab`, so it looks like that is indeed the culprit.

How do I fix this to mount the remote filesystem on boot?

Comment: What's the actual line you used in `fstab`? I use SSHFS in `fstab` without problems.

Comment: Hopefully you did the initial `sudo` steps from the tutorial?

Comment: @muru the actual line is `sshfs#jsevilla@machine.server.es:/home/jsevilla /mnt/talos`. I added it to the bottom of the `fstab` file

Comment: Is that all? What about the filesystem type and options?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I ran `sudo mkdir /mnt/talos`, `sudo sshfs -o allow_other root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/talos`, checked that the filesystem was correctly mounted, then `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and wrote `sshfs#jsevilla@machine.server.es:/home/jsevilla /mnt/talos` at the end of the file

Comment: @muru how do I specify the filesystem type and options?

Comment: @muru I have tried the suggested solution adding the line `sshfs#jsevilla@talos.gae.ucm.es:/home/jsevilla /mnt/talos fuse defaults,allow_other 0 0`; it has not worked :/

Comment: @Jsevillamol try `jsevilla@talos.gae.ucm.es:/home/jsevilla /mnt/talos fuse.sshfs defaults,allow_other 0 0` instead

Comment: @muru I tried, does not work either. To be clear, since I wrote the suggested solution and also with this line now it does no longer happen that the system goes to emergency mode, now it just fails silently

Comment: Then you probably need to set `IdentityFile`.